# Difficulties with multstore setup in magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, catalog

My main issue is that my catalog navigation does not show up on either of my magento store home pages. Here's the steps I took.

1. create root categories for each store view
2. create website, store and store view, linking to appropriate root category
3. change base urls for each view ie example.com/store1, example.com/store2 where store1 and store2 are my store codes
4. change default home page to a custom cms page
5. create a cms landing page where the customer will choose which store to visit by a url link that matches the url link of the store view.

My landing page with store links seems to work but when I test the links the catalog navigation won't appear. Is there a step that I missed that will make it appear?

Update:I setup parked domains for my two different stores thanking that might be the problem. The store urls seem to be working but it won't return the right theme or right catalog nav. I'm so confused right now, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to add the store code to the URL. Hope this helps someone who has experienced the same problem.